# How to write JSON data object in the isolated storage of my Windows Phone 8 application

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a problem that I have a list type ObservableCollection<>. i want save this list to a file JSON data object  in the isolated storage 
how use to ??

Comment: you mean json-encoded object? That's just a string of text. you'd store it like you would any OTHER string.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could save the ObservableCollection<> directly to IsolatedStorage:

```
        ObservableCollection<Person> obsPerson = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        //Storage
        IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["obsPerson"] = obsPerson;
        //Retrieval
        if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("obsPerson"))
        {
            ObservableCollection<Person> obsPerson = (ObservableCollection<person>)IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["obsPerson"];
        }
```